# There were Deployment Errors,Continue? in Xamain.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin.Android app from last one month.

I am facing the below error on each time I deploy to a mobile device.
Where as no error shown in Error List in Visual Studio 2015.

Output windows details is:

> Starting deploy OnePlus A0001 ...
> Deploying OnePlus A0001 ...
> Build started.
>
> **The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.**
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped

Comment: First, try deleting the app from your device.  If that doesn't work, look at the ADB logs to see if it gives you any insight into the installation error.

Comment: Could you share full build log? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/

Comment: it's amazing. I quarreled with this issue yesterday for 3 to 4 hours...but today when I Install app with previous apk file on mobile device and then delete it. and deploy from visual studio..it runs without error...I can't say what the actual problem was...but problem resolve ... thanks @Jason and Prashant